# Different Image shows for Site collector admin and other users for a webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a web part . I logged in as a site administrator and changed the image icon for the web part. As a site collection admin I can see my changed icon but for other users the older icon is displayed.

Any suggestions what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, Could be that the webpart has a failover image that it uses if the user does not have access to the one you selected.